# Alternative to iFrame to pull in actual data from an external website or form

Tags: php, html, iframe

OK... I'll try to be complete with my question (so, sorry for the lengthiness)... I've been trying to search all over the web for an ideal solution. I build our company's web site (self taught) and things are starting to come together with some nice css and php includes for my header and footer, and getting ready to use some Media Queries in my CSS with different browser sizes/resolutions and get some nice responsive web design going. As a product supplier in our industry, we upload product data into a service called Sage. They provide us with a personal website we CAN use that pulls in our product data that we give them. However, their site design isn't great and we'd like to just pull in the product data into our own existing site.

Currently our site pages for each product category just uses an iframe with the src URL pointing to the link generated by the results of [the search form](http://www.promoplace.com/ws/ws.dll/StartSrch?DistID=36182) on the Sage site they provide us. Obviously this isn't great since it's slow to pull the data in, and my iframe has to be sized to always fit the max height since i don't want scroll bars for the iframe.

Again, I am self taught with web development with my only tools being a healthy amount of google... and just reading source code, so if you have any recommendations, please be specific and detailed.

I have found something on this site posted by someone else that actually ALMOST works for me using the following code (I am testing at [this URL](http://promo-central.com/pens2) (if you want to see whats happening).

It's using the following code:

```
<?php $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.promoplace.com/ws/ws.dll/StartSrchDistID=36182&ProdSelect=&Srching=1&CatName=Pens&catmoveto=Pens&category=221&keywords=&itemnum=&LoP=&HiP=&Qty=&Search.x=44&Search.y=22&Search=submit&GlobalSearch=");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); ?>
<?php $result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); ?>
<?php $result = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+([\"'>]+)#",'$1http://www.promoplace.com/$2$3', $result);
echo $result ?>
```

If you look at my test page... the data is coming over well enough, but the external images don't display, and when you click through to view "more details" it appends the correct actual link data that should come after the external domain to MY domain, which points to a directory that exists externally, and not on my domain. It's obviously because the images are using links written for the directory locally. I am assuming that the $results = preg_replace..... ... command above is to in some way correct this, so maybe I am doing it wrong and I'm almost there already.

If anyone has any ideas, or a better, cleaner way to accomplish this, your help would be really greatly appreciated. I am really learning a lot, and enjoying it all.

Comment: You should as the `Sage` people if they provide an API for that sort of thing; going through their web-site and parsing the results seems a very painful and inefficient solution.

Comment: That preg_replace is only going to help with `<a href=""` tags. You might try something like: `str_replace('<img src="','<img src="http://www.promoplace.com',$result);` or think up a better regex.

Comment: @Brett interesting... you've helped me get a little better understanding of what this code actually means and what it's doing.  I created a new test page (/pens3) and used your bit of code with a minor adjustment: str_replace('src="','src="http://www.promoplace.com',$result);    thinking it would assist with links too. Doing this lets images load. Still have an issue with getting the deeper links to pull in data to my site.

Comment: @jeroen thanks! I just did some digging and found out that they do allow for this kind of integration ("The DataStream is an Internet-based interface that uses XML structured queries to obtain information."). I'm starting to look over the documentation. Unfortunately, it all is written for a programmer. So my basic understanding of web design does little to help me learn how to implement it. The documentation DOES make sense to me, and looks easy enough. I just don't know how to actually implement it into my site to make it DO something.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use iframe and you are using jQuery, you can do something like this. Try the following code:

Instead of an iframe tag use div tag

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

Place this code inside your `<head>` tag

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#divId').load(url of target website what you must load);     
});
</script>
</head>
```

All the contents from target site or page(specified url) will be inserted inside the `#divID` div tag. Hope this helps. All the best!

Comment: With this code would the page called be able to run PHP? I'm also trying to avoid iframes. Can I just drop the JS you have written into JS tags already in the header or does it need a library?

Comment: @krishan I'll give this a try in a little bit. Thanks for the response. I have yet to ever successfully implement any javascript. So, like Adam, I am curious about where to place this code, and what tags i need to wrap it in. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam you include this line on top of all other scripts in your head tag  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4'></script> then try

Comment: @Nate and Adam I have edited my answer. Please try now it should work. don't forget to add '#' before divId in java script

Comment: @kishan hey kishan thanks very much for the edit, I just wasn't using a JQuery library so that was the problem. It works to bring the content in perfectly however I can run the php inside the div. When I go to use the links in the content I'm returned to front page. No error warning why. I guess i'll stick to the iframe

Comment: @krishan Thanks for the clarification. I'm still getting nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong.  [Test page](http://promo-central.com/pens4)

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the original posters problem of making relative links work on the target website, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the object element which will allow you to click on links that target the child page.  Try this:

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" data="http://foo.com">
```

set your style to:

```
html, body{height: 100%;min-height: 100%;}
```

Make sure you set up CORS if the child page is NOT on the  same domain as the parent page.

Comment: An `<object>` pointing to an HTML document is (for almost all intents and purposes) exactly the same as an iframe, so this doesn't solve anything. CORS is irrelevant, it doesn't apply to displaying content in frames (or objects).